# Compare two dataframes with different size and create a new column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I've a large dataframe as shown below:

```
df1:
         Date      Code  ab-ret
0       1997-07-02  11     NaN
1       1997-07-04  11     NaN
2       1997-07-07  11     NaN
3       1997-07-08  11     NaN
4       1997-07-10  11     NaN
... ... ... ...
377395  2017-12-22  5757    -0.046651
377396  2017-12-26  5757    -0.017728
377397  2017-12-27  5757    0.024860
377398  2017-12-28  5757    0.016094
377399  2017-12-29  5757    -0.052789
377400 rows × 3 columns
```

I've a smaller dataframe as shown below:

```
df2:
              Date         Code
0           2009-03-17       11
1           2010-02-03       11
2           2011-02-14      363
3           2015-01-09      363
4           2010-10-15      365
...                ...      ...
9516        2015-02-24   449479
9517        2015-09-01   449479
9518        2016-04-01   449479
9519        2013-06-21   452095
9520        2015-05-06   553720

[9521 rows x 2 columns]
```

I want to compare columns `'Date'` and `'Code'` of each dataframe and whether a row in `df1` has the same `'Date'` and `'Code'` as in a given row of `df2` simultaneously. Based on that, I want to create a new column in `df1` which states `'True'` if the above mentioned condition is satisfied and `'false'` if not satisfied. How can it be done fast (not using loops is preferred as it takes a lot of time)?

P.S. All elements in a row from `df2.Date` and `df2.Code` aren't guaranteed to be in a given row of `df1.Date` and `df1.Code.` Also, I want all the rows in `df1` to remain( only looking to add a new column in `df1` stating if the corresponding `'Date'` and `'Code'` is present in `df2` or not). Hence, I'm not looking to merge or do an inner join.

Thus, I want the desired output as:

```
         Date      Code       ab-ret       Match
0       1997-07-02  11         NaN         False
1       1997-07-04  11         NaN         False
2       1997-07-07  11         NaN         False
3       1997-07-08  11         NaN         False
4       1997-07-10  11         NaN         False
... ... ... ...
377395  2017-12-22  5757    -0.046651      True
377396  2017-12-26  5757    -0.017728      True
377397  2017-12-27  5757    0.024860       True
377398  2017-12-28  5757    0.016094       False
377399  2017-12-29  5757    -0.052789      True
377400 rows × 4 columns
```

Comment: could you add the desired output please and what have you tried?

Comment: Why not do a left join? The structure of `df1` will remain unchanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a `merge` operation, use the parameter `indicator=True` to get a column named '_merge' close to the column 'Match' you want to create. Then just need to convert this column to False/True like in your expected output and `drop` the _merge column.

```
df1 = (df1.merge(df2, how='left', indicator=True)
          .assign(Match=lambda x: x['_merge'].eq('both'))
          .drop('_merge', axis=1)
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you could try also a tuple comparison by `pd.DataFrame.set_index()` and using `pd.DataFrame.isin`:

```
df1.set_index(['Date','Code']).index.isin(df2.set_index(['Date','Code']).index.to_list())
```

---

**Example**:

```
d={'Date': {0: pd.Timestamp('1997-07-02 00:00:00'), 1: pd.Timestamp('1997-07-04 00:00:00'), 2: pd.Timestamp('1997-07-07 00:00:00')}, 
   'Code': {0: 11, 1: 13, 2: 14}, 'ab-ret': {0: np.nan, 1: np.nan, 2: np.nan}}
df1=pd.DataFrame(d)
df1
#        Date  Code  ab-ret
#0 1997-07-02    11     NaN
#1 1997-07-04    13     NaN
#2 1997-07-07    14     NaN

d={'Date': {0: pd.Timestamp('1997-07-02 00:00:00'), 1: pd.Timestamp('1997-07-04 00:00:00')}, 
   'Code': {0: 11, 1: 11}, 'ab-ret': {0: np.nan, 1: np.nan}}
df2=pd.DataFrame(d)
df2
#        Date  Code  ab-ret
#0 1997-07-02    11     NaN
#1 1997-07-04    11     NaN

df1['Match']=df1.set_index(['Date','Code']).index.isin(df2.set_index(['Date','Code']).index.to_list())
df1
#        Date  Code  ab-ret  Match
#0 1997-07-02    11     NaN   True
#1 1997-07-04    13     NaN  False
#2 1997-07-07    14     NaN  False
```